# Add column value as id to each row of GridView in asp.net

Tags: gridview

I am using this code to give unique id to each row of GridView

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = e.Row;
   if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      row.Attributes["id"] = cRowID.ToString();
      cRowID++;
   }   
}
```

where **cRowID** is global integer variable.
This code gives me HTML code as

```
<table id="gridview1">
 <tr id="1"><td>...</td></tr>
 <tr id="2"><td>...</td></tr>
  .
  .  
 <tr id="n"><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I replace the cRowID with the specific column(say column1) value which is getting added to that same row?

**EDIT**
after adding the ID of tr tag in HTML I want it to become

```
<tr id="abc" ><td>abc</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr id="pqr" ><td>pqr</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr id="xyz" ><td>xyz</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

Is it possible? If yes, please explain how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested Try this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
     int counter=1;
     foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
     { 
        counter++;
        oItem.Cells[0].Text = counter.ToString();
        oItem.Attributes.Add("id", "yourvalue");//here you can set row id ie(<tr>)
     }
   }
```

**Edited**

```
foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
     { 
        string getFirstColValue = oItem.Cells[0].Text;
        oItem.Attributes.Add("id", getFirstColvalue );
     }
```

Comment: @PrasadJadhav: Sry i didn't get it, so expain it more what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: At run time GridView is rendered on page as HTML tag <table>. This table tag has <tr> tags. I want to give ID to this tr tag. Value of its Id (i.e. <tr id="this value">) will be value of first column in the table(i.e. value between first <td>this value</td>).

Comment: Gridview rendered on page as HTML tag <table>. so `<tr> tag is for Rows` and `<td> is for columns`.  SO `oItem.Cells[0].Text` indicates to oItem is row and cells[0] indicates Firstcolumn.

Comment: :thanks, it worked!!! just out of curiosity, can we able to assign primary key value instead of assigning first column value so that the ids we are assigning will be unique?

Comment: @PrasadJadhav: yes u can set unique values, all you need to assign value of string variable and later add attributes id

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go through a loop. The code given below is working fine:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string getFirstColValue = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("id", getFirstColvalue );            
    }
}
```